# Creating a list of lists of items based on first value in list

Tags: python, list

I have a list like for example this one [[19, 2], [19, 3], [16, 4], [16, 5]] and I need to make a list of lists that groups the second values in the lists based on the first values. So in this example I'd expect the output [[2, 3],[4, 5]]. I need it to work for a general number of lists matching the first value, with a general number of unique first values. All the sublists will always have only two values and there will always be atleast two matching sublists from one value (i.e. if there's a list in the list of lists there's at least one other list that has the same first value). Hope my explanation is understandable.

Examples of inputs and expected outputs:
input: [[24, 0], [24, 1], [24, 2], [20, 5], [20, 6], [16, 8], [16, 9], [0, 10], [0, 11], [0, 12]]
output: [[0, 1, 2], [5, 6], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

input: [[21, 0], [21, 1]]
output: [[0,1 ]]

input: [[60, 1], [60, 2], [34, 5], [34, 6], [34, 7], [29, 9], [29, 10], [11, 13], [11, 14], [11, 15], [11, 16]]
output:[[1, 2], [5, 6, 7], [9, 10], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Please provide the code you have written

Comment: @MariaKozlova I've tried this:  out = [[lst[1], i[1]] for lst in input for i in input if lst[0] == i[0] and input.index(lst) != input.index(i)]. But with this method i get duplicates for example [[2, 3], [3, 2]], when I really want to get just [[2, 3]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store and update the elements of the groups.

```
input_list = [[60, 1], [60, 2], [34, 5], [34, 6], [34, 7], [29, 9], [29, 10], [11, 13], [11, 14], [11, 15], [11, 16]]
groups = {}

for sub_list in input_list:
    if sub_list[0] in groups:
        groups[sub_list[0]].append(sub_list[1])
    
    else:
        groups[sub_list[0]] = [sub_list[1]]

print(list(groups.values()))
```

I am using this code to store the groups in a dictionary, if the group is not present then it is initialized, otherwise for an existing group, elements are appended to the group's list.

I am getting your expected output with this code.

```
[[1, 2], [5, 6, 7], [9, 10], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the `groupby` function from `itertools with list comprehension` to group by the desired value and then extract the values in each `group` to form the sub-lists:

```
from itertools import groupby

mylist = [[60, 1], [60, 2], [34, 5], [34, 6], [34, 7], [29, 9], [29, 10], [11, 13], [11, 14], [11, 15], [11, 16]]

group_list =  [[i[1] for i in group] for key, group in groupby(mylist,key=lambda x: x[0])]

print(group_list) 
#output [[1, 2], [5, 6, 7], [9, 10], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

you could check [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) library to learn more about the great functionality in it.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a list of the second indices, grouped by the value of the first index in the two-value sublists? At least, that is what I understood.

Here is a small example that could be helpful to understand what could be done:

```
lofl=[[60, 1], [60, 2], [34, 5], [34, 6], [34, 7], [29, 9], [29, 10], [11, 13], [11, 14], [11, 15], [11, 16]] 

lfin=[[]]
comparison = lofl[0][0]  # set comparison to the first value
for x in lofl:
 if x[0]==comparison:    # same group
  lfin[-1].append(x[1])
 else:                   # comparison value changed -> new group
  comparison=x[0]
  lfin.append([x[1]])
  
print (lfin)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works exactly as intended. You understood it great, I'm sorry for not explaining it clearly, I'm quite new to python.